# How to add 2 DataSets together

Tags: c#, sql

My question is pretty simple. I have 2 DataSets and I want to add them together in a way that DataSet1's Table[1]'s first Cell's Value gets concatenated with DataSet2's Table[1]'s first Cell's Value.

For Example, lets suppose, in DataSet1's Table[1]'s first cells value is `01` and DataSet2's Table[1]'s first cell value is `General Requirements`, I want to combine (concatenate) these two values from 2 different Datasets to be stored in a 3rd DataSet's Table[1]'s first Cell as `01,General Requirements`.

Comment: Are the datasets populated from the same database?

Comment: you can use the `Merge` method

Answer (score 0):

try

```
DataSet.Merge() // DataSet
```

for further Notes http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.merge.aspx ... Accept answer if your code is working

Comment: I have difficulties to see how your answer will satisfy the following requirement expressed by OP:  `I want to combine (concatenate) these two values from 2 different Datasets to be stored in a 3rd DataSet's Table[1]'s first Cell as 01,General Requirements.`

Comment: Every one wont write whole code..we can just give idea...you have to work on it ...

Comment: No need to write the whole code, but your suggestion (_the idea you give_) is not applicable in this particular case. Unless I am mistaken [DataSet.Merge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4swwh51k.aspx) method does not concatenate fields. As an example, @unlimit 's answer does not give total working code but the code snippet he shares with us is coherent with the context of OP's question. Of course when someone asks questions , he/she has to work on it. But when we answer a question, don't we **have to work on it** too?

Comment: Who said it wont concatenate... you can add Rows of any datatable to the current dataset....go and read about DataSet in Msdn ...

Comment: Elegant answer, I'd suggest to avoid comments like `go and read about DataSet in Msdn` and to **read carefully** what OP is asking!What OP is asking is not to simply merge two datasets so that missing dataRows in one could be added (and not concatenated) to another one.He wants to be able to merge two datasets in a special way so that the values in the rows are concatenated.`If in one row 0 of table 0 of dataset 1 I have 'Beautiful' and on other row 0 of the table 0 of dataset 2 I have 'life',he wants as a merge result one row with 'beautiful life' and not two rows with 'beautiful' and 'life'`

Answer (score 0):

One of the way to do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataset2.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
  dataset1.Tables[0].Rows[i][0] = 
          dataset1.Tables[0].Rows[i][0] + "," + dataset2.Tables[0].Rows[i][0];
```

This will concatenate `dataset2`'s first table's first column with `dataset1`'s first table's first column. Note that I have assumed that the columns are of `string` datatype. You may have to check for `null` etc.

Answer (score 0):

1. I don't understand your requirement but is this what you are expecting?

`var ds1=new DataSet();
var ds2=new DataSet();
ds1.Tables.Add(ds2.Tables[1]);`

1. You can Merge two datasets using 
   `ds1.Merge(ds2)`

Answer (score 0):

```
//get column 1 data to a list from dataset1
var list1 = ds1.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(x => x[0].ToString());
//get column 1 data to a list from dataset2
var list2 = ds2.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(x => x[0].ToString());
//merge two list items 
var mergedList = list1.Zip(list2, (a, b) => a + " ," + b);
// create new datatable 
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("ColumnName", typeof(string)); // give proper column name
foreach (string item in mergedList)
{
    dt.Rows.Add(item); // add each item as row 
}
DataSet ds3 = new DataSet(); 
// add newly created table to dataset 3
ds3.Tables.Add(dt);
```